# Just a little error while making a Java Game

Tags: java, audio, javasound

ok so I have this code and it's working while i play it in Eclipse. but when i export it , it doesn't play any sound at all.. how should i export it or what should I do to make it work?

```
package sound;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
public class GameSounds 
{
    public static synchronized void hit()
    {
        try
        {
            String resPath = "/sounds/8bit_bomb_explosion.wav"; // *** this is the key ***
            InputStream audioInStream = GameSounds.class.getResourceAsStream(resPath);
            System.out.println("is audioInStream null?: " + (audioInStream == null)); // test it!
            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioInStream);          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(inputStream);
            clip.start(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

there is no error .. i think the problem is the export.. i just press export and then i select executable jar file.. everything works but the audio not..

and there is no exception thrown

by logging output you mean that "is audioInStream null?" if yes the output is false
and there is no exception thrown

Comment: So what is your logging output? And is an exception thrown?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: Check the content of your jar. Does it contain a file `8bit_bomb_explosion.wav` under the folder `sounds`? Remember that a jar file is just a zip file with a .jar extension.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you are using InputStream's and that they might be tested for markability and resetability. Audio files generally do not support either, so some sort of exception will be triggered.

The solution is to use a URL instead. Then you can arrive at an AudioInputStream without going through the intermediate InputStream step.

Thus, instead of building a String, build a URL and give this as the input parameter to the getResourceAsStream() method. If you look at the spec for this method, you will see three overloadings: File, URL, InputStream. I find URL to work the best, as a URL can specify a resource packed in a JAR file, and is not tested for mark/reset errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your path is incorrect, or the inputstream is not working properly, I don't know how many times i have exported a project and a resource does not load correctly. I recommend that you run your jar with command prompt or terminal, either way i think the command is the same.

The reason why I recommend you run it from cmd/terminal is because any errors that might occur will appear in cmd/terminal and then you can start breaking down the problem a little more

-java jar PathAndNameOfJar.jar

[heres a video](http://youtu.be/vUjcqnWbOJo)